# ManyToMany relation is not updating/inserting in the association table

Tags: hibernate, gwt, jpa, many-to-many

I have 2 Hibernate objects Group and User which are related with a ManyToMany relationship.

I use the following mapping

Group.java

```
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>(0);

...

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)  
@JoinTable(name = "user_group",
joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID") },
inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") })
public Set<User> getUsers() {
    return this.users;
}
...
```

User.java

```
private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<User>(0);

...


@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users") 
public Set<Group> getGroups() {
    return this.groups;
}

...
```

DAO.java

```
public User addUserToGroup (Integer groupId , Integer  userId){
    Group group = (Group) getBeanById(groupId, Group.class); //Here I get the right group
    User user = (User) getBeanById(userId, User.class);//Here I get the right user
    group.getUsers().add(user);
    user.getGroups().add(group);
    save(group);        
    return user;
}
```

The save method

```
public EntityBase save(EntityBase transientInstance) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
    log.debug("persisting  instance");
    try {
        session.saveOrUpdate(transientInstance);
        log.debug("persist successful");
        return transientInstance;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("save failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}
```

My problem is when I add a user to a groupe, no record is added to the association table `user_group`.

NB : The begin and commit statements are called in a filter Servlet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code above does what it should do.
My problem was at the display of the list of the users, Hibernate detect a dirty users collections and delete it. What I ended up doing is to change the ownership of the relationship to Group instead of the User, and all behaved normally.

Comment: logically thinking: a group can be empty, but a user has to be in a group. So that makes group the parent.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call like this

```
save(group); 
user.getGroups().add(group);
save(user);
```

you dont need to update the other side of the entity, as it will be updated by hibernate.

Comment: group is not a transient object so no need for the save because hibernate has already loaded the instance